# FreeBSD sysctl.conf kernel.panic parametr?

Tags: kernel, freebsd

There is a `kernel.panic` param in Linux's `/etc/sysctl.conf` to auto-reboot the OS when the kernel crashes.

Is there anything like this in FreeBSD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want

> debug.debugger_on_panic

See [The Developer Handbook section on kernel debugging](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/kerneldebug-options.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

FreeBSD - just like perhaps every other Unix system other than Linux - reboots after panic automatically.